# How to create a 2D mesh with refinement? Python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I create a mesh with refinement, lets say x and y go from 0 to 1 and between 0.4 and 0.6 in both directions I want the points to be closer.

I have been reading about numpy.logspace, but it doesnt allow much freedom.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one specific command with this functionality, but you can build arrays up with `numpy.concatenate` this way:

```
import numpy

start = 0
end = 1
bigstep = 0.1

refinedstart = 0.4
refinedend = 0.6
smallstep = 0.01

x = numpy.concatenate([numpy.arange(start, refinedstart, bigstep),
                       numpy.arange(refinedstart, refinedend, smallstep),
                       numpy.arange(refinedend, end, bigstep)])
```

Comment: That could be a solution. But what if I want to make progressive steps(like in np.logspace)? @chthonicdaemon

Comment: You'd have to define "progressive steps" more mathematically. `numpy.logspace` specifically generates logarithmically spaced points (in other words each point is 10**x where x varies linearly). If you want logarithmically spaced points, you can just use logspace where I used arange. If you want some other spacing, you'll have to figure out what formula describes the relationship and then code that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to "squash" the middle values.  But say you want to do it quadratically, using an 11-by-11 grid spanning from -10 to 10 on each axis:

```
a = np.linspace(-np.sqrt(10), np.sqrt(10), 11)
b = np.sign(a)*a**2
x, y = np.meshgrid(b, b)
```

To see what this grid looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), '*')
plt.show()
```